# How do I destroy a SDL_Finger pointer?

Tags: c++, sdl, memory

Hello I'm using SDL with C++ and I got this code:

```
void handleEvents() {
    SDL_Finger* finger = SDL_GetTouchFinger(SDL_GetTouchDevice(0), 0);
}
```

I do not know what SDL does inside the GetTouch function, maybe it allocates memory. Do I have to "destroy" finger here? Or will it be deleted by the end of the methods scope?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a quick glance at the SDL wiki at the function you provided, it says:

"The returned resource is owned by SDL and should not be deallocated."

from - https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetTouchFinger

Therefor, you shouldn't need to worry about destroying the object, SDL will manage it for you.